# inode map in log structured file systems

Tags: linux, operating-system

In log structured file systems, there are data blocks, inode, and inode map. inode has a number; I think it is like an offset of a disk. If we know an inode number, we know the offset of the disk, i.e, the location at the disk.

Wonder why inode map is needed?